# Symfony2 cache directory permissions

Tags: apache, symfony, caching, permissions

Sorry, I'm new to Symfony.

I think I've tried everything here. I'm trying to install a Symfony v2.8 application on a new machine. When I'm trying to access the application I'm getting exceptions stating lack of permissions to access either cache or logs directory. Cache and logs directories are writeable though - mask 777 set for both. 
Also there seems to be a process that creates entries in the cache directory as it fills in with files. The problem seems to be that the web server can't access them - but why?

getfacl for both cache and logs directories returns this:

```
# owner: apache
# group: apache
user::rwx
user:apache:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:apache:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: official doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/setup/file_permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

Check that you logs and cache are being put in the correct location. Symfony has "**two**" **major** development environments (**dev** and **prod**). They (env) write **logs** and **caches** in **two separate folders**. Check the **getCacheDir()** and **getLogDir()** methods in the **app/AppKernel.php**.